# WPF DependencyProperty expose a control property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a UserControl with a TextBox and I want to expose `TextBox.Text` property. We must take into consideration that `TextBox.Text` and the DependencyProperty binded to it, are not always the same values. And I explain it a little bit deeper:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MySolution.MyUserControl"
             Name="MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>This is my label</TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=BindingText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And this code-behind:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace MySolution
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string BindingText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(BindingTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BindingTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(BindingText), typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
                {
                    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
                });
}
```

In this simple example, if we run the application and we type "Hello" in `myTextBox` **and we do not lose the focus**, we would have that `TextBox.Text` is "Hello", but `BindingText` (our DependencyProperty) is still empty (until we lose the focus and the binding updates).

In other words, what I would like is to be able to bind to something like this:

```
public string Text
{
    get => myTextBox.Text;
    set => myTextBox.Text = value;
}
```

But I this does not work, I guess because it is not a DependencyProperty. Is it possible to create a DependencyProperty that exposes `myTextBox.Text` anyway?

Comment: Why would you not set UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged?

Comment: Alternatively, derive from TextBox and move the TextBlock to the ControlTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens even with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged there are moments when both properties would be different, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592040/xaml-binding-with-delay-and-keybinding/

Comment: @Clemens could you explain a little bit more the ControlTemplate option, please? It sounds interesting... Thank you

Comment: You would derive from TextBox and change the TextBox Template so that it contains the TextBlock. You will find the default ControlTemplate e.g. here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @Clemens I think I will explore that way. I will report you if I have success, and I will ask you for writing it as answer if so.

Comment: For the "moments when both properties would be different" - you would simply not use a delayed Binding. Do not overcomplicate it.

Comment: Make sure your custom ControlTemplate keeps the `<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>` part. Do not put another TextBox into it, a common mistake.

Comment: @Clemens Your suggestion was great for me, now I even wonder why I used a UserControl instead of extending an existing control in a lot of more places... If you write it as an answer, explaining it a little for other people in the future, I will mark it as accepted answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From my limited testing, this solution appears to be sufficient for your needs

Code behind:

```
public partial class MyUserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get => myTextBox.Text;
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(testControl1),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
}
```

XAML:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>This is my label</TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyControl,Path=Text, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I am little bit busy right now and I cannot test if it works for me. I will test it later, and if it works for me, I will mark your answer. Thank you

Comment: `Box.Text = value;` is pointless, or even wrong. The setter of the Text property will not be called when the Text dependency property is set by data binding and a couple of other sources. There must not be anything else than the SetValue call in the setter.

Comment: @Clemens gotcha. I knew there was something redundant in the setter and I thought it was the SetValue call, but then when I removed SetValue it no longer worked. I guess I don't understand dependency properties as well as I should

Comment: They are however perfectly documented.

Comment: @Carlos any luck?